# Can't highlight a single word on this webpage using Edge or Firefox

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm semi-new to javascript so I hopefully won't get lost on suggested answers. I have a website that I'm trying to figure out why I cannot left click and drag to highlight a single word. The webpage won't let me. Can someone explain how the web developer was able to accomplish this ? Thanks in advance.

Here is the webpage:

[www.minimalismmadesimple.com](https://www.minimalismmadesimple.com/home/self-validation/)

Comment: We will only tell you if you promise that you're not trying to emulate this horrible practice, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily accomplished using CSS.

```css
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Try and select me</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**I must mention that this usually is bad for UX!** Unless you have an absolutely good reason to use this, you shouldn't be making life harder for other people to use your website.

Also, W3Schools will help you a lot with web: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_disable_text_selection.asp

Comment: Thank you @AmparoWalter. I was able to modify the offline html page which I had downloaded and got the text selection and copy right click menu working. All in all it was worth the learning experience. Thanks for the information it did help.